# RTCTokenBuilder Agora in Flutter keep said invalidAppID

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I try to developed video call app using agora with flutter, i need to get Agora Token from server with PHP. i try using code in https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/php/sample/RtcTokenBuilderSample.php

Its can build a token , but rejected by agora , and keep said "Invalid APP ID".
I tried to change RTC Token Builder result with Temp Token from Agora , and its work well.

Help me , what's wrong with my RTC Token Builder ? any idea ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `appId` and `appCertificate` with your own ones. Hope you have already created a project at https://console.agora.io/ where you can find your own `appId` and `appCertificate` for a given project.